# How do transactions within Oracle stored procedures work? Is there an implicit transaction?

Tags: sql, oracle

In an Oracle stored procedure, how do I write a transaction?  Do I need to do it explicitly or will Oracle automatically lock rows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might want to browse the [concept guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/toc.htm), in particular the chapter about [transactions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/intro.htm#sthref266):

> A transaction is a logical unit of work that comprises one or more SQL statements run by a single user. [...] A transaction begins with the user's first executable SQL statement. A transaction ends when it is explicitly committed or rolled back by that user.

You don't have to explicitely start a transaction, it is done automatically. You will have to specify the end of the transaction with a commit (or a rollback).

The locking mechanism is a fundamental part of the DB, read about it in the chapter [Data Concurrency and Consistency](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/toc.htm).

---

#### Regarding stored procedures

A stored procedure is a set of statements, they are executed in the same transaction as the calling session (*). Usually, transaction control (commit and rollback) belongs to the calling application. The calling app has a wider vision of the process (which may involve several stored procedures) and is therefore in a better position to determine if the data is in a consistent state. While you can commit in a stored procedure, it is not the norm.

(*) except if the procedure is declared as an autonomous transaction, in which case the procedure is executed as an independent session (*thanks [be here now](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272864/be-here-now), now I see your point*).

Comment: I guess you should also mention autonomous transactions here.

Comment: What happens if my stored procedure contains DML but no commit statement?

Comment: @AdamStevenson - if there is no commit in the procedure, the transaction will be ended by the session that calls it; any locks will be held until the session issues a commit (or rollback). If it doesn't ever explicitly do so then the session will implicitly perform a commit or rollback when it ends, depending on how it is terminated. The transaction may exist before the procedure call to. The procedure is one statement within the transaction.

Comment: @AdamStevenson: I updated my answer, I hope it's a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

@AdamStevenson Concerning DDL, there's a cite from the Concept's Guide:

> If the
>       current transaction contains any DML statements, Oracle first commits
>   the
>       transaction, and then runs and commits the DDL statement as a new,
>   single
>       statement transaction.

So if you have started a transaction before the DDL statement (e.g. wrote an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE statements), the transaction started will be implicitly commited - you should always keep that in mind when processing DML statements.

I agree with Vincent Malgrat, you might find some very useful information about transaction processing at the Concept's Guide.